# How can I prevent Gitblit to pack a git repository?

Tags: gitblit

I've noticed that gitblit doesn't recognize unpacked git repositories per default.

Can I configure gitblit in such a way, that unpacked git repositories are recognized?

Comment: Can you rephrase "unpacked repositories"?  I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: If I push some data to a repository in gitblit the data will be compressed. But I want to push uncompressed data to a repository. e.g. if I create manually an uncompressed git repository in the gitblit "git.repositoriesFolder" and restart Tomcat the created repository isn't recognized by Gitblit.

Comment: Sorry for my previous posts. They are a little bit confusing. My question is: Why can I only push to bare git repositories in gitblit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pushing to a repository with a work tree can have dangerous and unintended results.  It is considered a best practice to only push to a bare repository.  If you search StackOverflow or Google you will find many explanations on *why*.  One good explanation is available [here](http://www.bitflop.com/document/111), but there are others.  Bare repositories are meant to be used as the centralized distribution point for development.  Gitblit will allow you to view repositories with attached worktrees but it will not allow you to push into them.